# how to retrive JSON data by using swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

I am retrieving datas from JSON by using swift. I am new to JSON. I don't how to retrieve this nested values. My previous question is [Issue raised, while retriving datas from JSON by using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649862/issue-raised-while-retriving-datas-from-json-by-using-swift) . I got clarified. This is new to me. My JSON format is below. Kindly guide me.

JSON Response formats:

```
{

"salutation": {
                "id": 1,
                "salutation": "Mr"
                },
"firstName": "AAA",
"middleName": "BBB",
"lastName": "C",
"employeeId": "RD484",

"station": {
                "id": 86,
                "stationCode": null,
                "stationName": "DDD",
                "subDivision": null,
                "address": null
                },
"subDivsion": {
                "id": 11,
                "divisionCode": "11",
                "divisionDesc": "EEE",
                "division": null
                }
}
```

//My Attempt:

```
 var maindict = NSDictionary() //Global declaration

 var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

 //now create the NSMutableRequest object using the url object
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
 request.HTTPMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

 var err: NSError?
 request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &err) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

  request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
  request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
  var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
  println("Response: \(response)")
  self.maindict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as [String: AnyObject]
  var err: NSError?
  var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

  // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
  if(err != nil) {
  println(err!.localizedDescription)
  let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  //println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
  }
  else {
  // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
  // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
  if let parseJSON = json {

  // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
  var success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
  println("Succes: \(success)")

  self.dataFromJSON() //METHOD CALLING

  }
  else {
  // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
  let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
  //println("AUTHENTICATION FAILED")
   }
  }
 })

  task.resume()


func dataFromJSON()
    {
     println("Main Dict Values: \(maindict)") //PRINTING ALL VALUES
     let dataArray = maindict["firstName"] as? [String:AnyObject]   
     println("FirstName Values: \(dataArray)") // PRINTING NIL VALUES
    }
```

Comment: It's not that different from your last question. You can use the same techniques I gave you in my answer to your last question.

Comment: but I am facing error.

Comment: can u teach me once again @EricD.

Comment: Then edit your question by adding your error, otherwise we can't guess... I will help you, of course.

Comment: Here no array values know. Then how can i move?? last time,, we had changed to array of dictionary. this time??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue raised, while retriving datas from JSON by using swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649862/issue-raised-while-retriving-datas-from-json-by-using-swift)

Comment: Getting NIL Values. @EricD. I updated in my attempt. Can u guide me?

Comment: R u thr @EricD. Having one mor doudt

Comment: Go to the [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79320/discussion-between-eric-d-and-mcdonal-11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure does not begin with an array this time, but with a Dictionary. Your structure is like is:

> root Dictionary -> "salutation" -> Dictionary
>   root Dictionary -> "station"    -> Dictionary
>   root Dictionary -> "subDivsion" -> Dictionary

Let's say you want to access the "id" of "salutation", then:

```
// Just an exemple of how to download, surely you have your own way
func getJSON(url: NSURL) {
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, downloadError) -> Void in
        if let error = downloadError {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            var jsonError: NSError?

            // cast the result as a Dictionary
            if let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as? [String: AnyObject] {

                // print the dictionary to check contents
                println(dict)

                if let salutationDictionary = dict["salutation"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    if let id = salutationDictionary["id"] as? Int {

                        println(id)

                    }

                }

            }
            if jsonError != nil {
                println(jsonError)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**EDIT:**

My friend, your code was a mess... I suggest to you to do some cleaning when you've got errors, it helps to debug. Anyway, here's a corrected version of your new code. Pay attention to how `maindict` is declared on the first line. Also, you had one unnecessary call to `NSJSONSerialization`, I simplified it. Note: for the sake of the example, I've included your `dataFromJSON` function code directly inside `if let parseJSON ...`, but of course it doesn't mean you have to do the same.

```
var maindict: [String: AnyObject]?

var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
//let parameters = ...

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: your_url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &err)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    println("Response: \(response)")

    var err: NSError?
    maindict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &err) as? [String: AnyObject]

    if err != nil {

        println(err!.localizedDescription)

    } else {

        if let parseJSON = maindict {

            var success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
            println("Succes: \(success)")

            println("Main Dict Values: \(maindict)")
            let firstName = maindict!["firstName"] as? String
            println("FirstName: \(firstName)")

        }
        else {

            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")

        }
    }
})

task.resume()
```

*Please pay attention to the details and study my modifications by comparing with your attempt. My answer has been tested on my own server and it works, so you can use it as a working base.*

Comment: Hi.. Eric D. ,, Now I am having all response in **mainDictValues** (Dictionary)

Comment: if let salutationDictionary = mainDictValues["salutation"] as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    if let id = salutationDictionary["id"] as? Int {

                        println(id)

                    }

                }

Comment: Try my example. Now it's better to use Swift's Dictionaries (like `[String: AnyObject]`) than NSDictionary (if you don't need Objective-C automatic compatibility).

Comment: **println("FirstName Values: \(dataArray)")** again printing nil

Comment: I've updated my example for your data. Suggestion: *look at your data!* In your JSON, `maindict!["firstName"]` is a String, not a Dictionary. So of course it's nil if it's cast as a Dictionary.

Comment: THen,, how to get the value?

Comment: Really its too tough to face it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79320/discussion-between-eric-d-and-mcdonal-11).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a library.

1) You can use swiftyJSON. It uses the objective C JSON parsing library.
https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

2) If you want a library which uses a pure swift parser try JSONSwift. **The readme on github shows how you can retrieve nested values from the JSON file.** And integrating it in your project just requires you to import a single file. https://github.com/geekskool/JSONSwift